# Powershell job crashes all shell - how to catch an error?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I want to get serial numbers of all PC in AD with Powershell jobs.
When I run a script, all shell crashes and restarts.
I found one PC that cause a problem, and run script for only it.

```
$PCNameNewArray=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@("proektor-bnu")

$arrayJobs = @()

try {
    $arrayJobs = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $PCNameNewArray -Class Win32_BIOS -asjob -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    catch {}

Wait-Job $arrayJobs

$arrayJobs | Receive-Job | Format-Table PsComputerName, SerialNumber -AutoSize
```

That's my script for one PC.
If I use another PC, but no "proektor-bnu", it works OK.
If I use this PC - all shell just crashes and restarts.
How can I catch, what cause a problem? Or how can I ignore this PC?
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "all shell just crashes and restarts"? Are you talking about the GUI shell, explorer, and the Windows taskbar? Or just the instance of `powershell.exe` running the code? Or all instance of `powershell.exe`? What happens during "restart"? Does powershell start running the same script again?

Comment: Only Powershell.exe, all instance of Powershell. Nothing happens with windows Explorer. Powershell restarts and sometimes it opens my script again (but not running again), sometimes - just blank powershell GUI.